# Getting size of NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I've been trying to get the size of an NSAttributedString like this:

```
CGSize myPaperSize = CGSizeMake(myPaperWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0f];

//TODO: Fix problem with printing. When we print it's overlapping because of how the printer gets its size

/**

    We currently want to do it by the size of the text. But for some reason it only does it well for two lines. Over two lines overlaps
 */

NSMutableParagraphStyle* style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

//Attributes of my text
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:newFormatter.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style}];

CGRect stringRect = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:paperRect options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
CGSize stringSize = CGSizeMake(stringRect.size.width, stringRect.size.height);


//Here I want to update the size of the paper by adding the distance from last formatter plus whatever the height of the string is.
self.slipHeight += distanceFromFormatterAbove + ceil(stringSize.height);
```

This works when the text is two lines on my piece of paper. But when the text is more than 3 lines it doesn't work. Any one have any idea how to get this to work (ios7)? Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading to your options in boundRectWithSize

```
CGRect stringRect = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:paperRect options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
```

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. One thing I noticed that could be wrong is that on my printing paper, I have the text aligned center. Should I also specify that on my attributes? I'm imagining that could give me incorrect values.

Comment: What is the size boundingRectWithSize is returning? Is it the same width as you'd expect?